# error in before method in Calendar class in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, calendar

I working with Calendar class in java and found that there is a bug in "after" and " getTimeInMillis" methods. these methods work correctly for always all calendar but some special calendar they have problem.
My test code is :

```
   Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
   Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
   c1.set(2006, 5, 31, 22, 0, 0);
   c2.set(2006, 6, 1, 1, 0, 0);
   if (c1.after(c2))
       System.out.println("c1 is after c2.");
   if (c1.getTimeInMillis()>c2.getTimeInMillis())
       System.out.println("c1 in mimisecond is greater than c2");
```

although c1 is before c2 but my code print:
c1 is after c2.
c1 in mimisecond is greater than c2

What is the problem? How can I resolve it?
I use Java NetBeans 7.1 IDE and  JDK 1.7.

Comment: A bug in `Calendar`? Somewhat unlikely...

Answer (score 5):

Since there are only 30 days in June (5 corresponds to June, since the numbering of months start at 0), they point to the same day. Therefore `c1` is in fact a later date than `c2`.

To avoid this confusion, you could use the constants in the `Calendar` class:

```
c1.set(2006, Calendar.MAY, 31, 22, 0, 0);
c2.set(2006, Calendar.JUNE, 1, 1, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Therefore, it's better to use the predefined constants for months in the Calendar class, e.g `Calendar.MAY`. You could also set it to non-lenient, and it would throw an exception.